# Error while launching robotframework-RIDE (Robot Framework IDE)

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have installed Robot Framework and installed wxPython and then Ride. When I launch it by executing `python ride.py`, it runs into an error as shown below. I believe it has something to do with the wxPython version, not sure.

There is a series of `UnreprError` like this

```
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 0.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 3.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 4.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 5.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 6.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 7.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 19.
...
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 60.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 61.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 62.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 63.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 67.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 68.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 69.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 70.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 71.
    <class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 13.
```

And then the stack trace shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line 58, in OnInit
    self.frame = RideFrame(self, self._controller)
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 175, in __init__
    self._init_ui()
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 279, in _init_ui
    self.tree = Tree(self, self.actions,
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\tree.py", line 86, in __init__
    self._images = TreeImageList()
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 42, in __init__
    TestCaseController: _TreeImage(self, 'robot.png'),
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.normal = self._get_image(image_list, normal)
  File "c:\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 91, in _get_image
    img = wx.Image(path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ..\..\src\common\intl.cpp(1579) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
OnInit returned false, exiting...
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at ..\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(478) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed
```

Here is what I have installed on Python 3.8.3 on Windows 10 (win32)

```
wxPython==4.0.7.post2
six==1.15.0
Pypubsub==4.0.3
Pillow==7.1.2
Pygments==2.6.1
pywin32==228
robotframework==3.2.1
robotframework-ride==1.7.4.2
```

Comment: I have got the same error with robotframework-ride==1.7.4.2 and Python 3.8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RIDE 1.7.4.2 is not compatible with Python 3.8.
It should not even install when using `pip`.

You should uninstall RIDE 1.7.4.2, and install the Beta version by executing the following command:

```
c:\Python38-32\python.exe -m pip install --pre robotframework-ride
```

See more info in the [Project Page](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE) or in the [FAQ](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/F.A.Q.).

Comment: Yes, it works for me after uninstalling RIDE 1.7.4.2, and installing the Beta version (robotframework-ride==2.0b1)

Comment: This worked. 
Ideally You need to downgrade the wxPython version (as observed the working version is 4.0.7) and the uninstall if already installed robotframework-ride and the run this command pip install -U --pre robotframework-ride