# How to remove parse error from robot framework-ride

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have 64bit windows-10 system. I have installed Python 3.8.5 and wxPython==4.0.7.post2(wxpython is installed using pip- "pip install -U wxPython") and also set up environment variables for the path of python and python/script.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDlBI.png)

When i launch ride using ride.py in cmd it does nothing. showing following---
C:\Users\Varun Tygai>ride.py
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 0.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 3.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 4.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 5.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 6.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 7.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 19.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 20.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 21.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 22.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 25.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 26.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 27.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 28.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 29.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 30.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 31.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 32.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 33.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 34.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 35.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 36.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 37.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 38.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 39.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 40.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 43.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 44.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 45.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 46.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 47.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 48.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 49.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 50.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 51.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 52.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 53.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 54.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 55.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 56.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 57.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 58.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 59.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 60.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 61.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 62.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 63.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 67.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 68.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 69.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 70.
<class 'robotide.preferences.configobj.UnreprError'> Parse error in value at line 71.
Creating librarykeywords database to "C:\Users\Varun Tygai\AppData\Roaming\RobotFramework\ride\librarykeywords.db"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\application\application.py", line 58, in OnInit
self.frame = RideFrame(self, self._controller)
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 175, in **init**
self._init_ui()
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\mainframe.py", line 279, in _init_ui
self.tree = Tree(self, self.actions,
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\tree.py", line 86, in **init**
self._images = TreeImageList()
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 42, in **init**
TestCaseController: _TreeImage(self, 'robot.png'),
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 80, in **init**
self.normal = self._get_image(image_list, normal)
File "c:\users\varun tygai\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\robotide\ui\images.py", line 91, in _get_image
img = wx.Image(path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG).ConvertToBitmap()
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "strcmp(setlocale(LC_ALL, NULL), "C") == 0" failed at ....\src\common\intl.cpp(1579) in wxLocale::GetInfo(): You probably called setlocale() directly instead of using wxLocale and now there is a mismatch between C/C++ and Windows locale.
Things are going to break, please only change locale by creating wxLocale objects to avoid this!
OnInit returned false, exiting...
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
wx._core.wxAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at ....\src\common\wincmn.cpp(478) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63140326/error-while-launching-robotframework-ride

Comment: ok, got it , thanks:)